# C# PHP-CGI with cookie support

Tags: c#, php, cookies, server, cgi

I´m trying to create a WebServer and it´s working with HTML, Images...
But I want to implement PHP and I have a working implementation of PHP-CGI but it doesn't work with stuff like 'file_get_contents' and cookies.
And I was wondering if there is a way to fix that?

```
private string ProcessPHP(string phpPath, CookieCollection cookies)
{
    Process CGI = new Process();
    CGI.StartInfo.FileName = "php\\php.exe";
    CGI.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    CGI.StartInfo.Arguments = "-q \"" + phpPath + "\"";
    CGI.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    CGI.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    CGI.Start();

    string OutputText = CGI.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    CGI.WaitForExit();
    CGI.Close();

    return OutputText;
}
```

And I know that I´m not doing anything with the CookieCollection but I want to know how to use it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but currently the windows version of php ships with a separate `php-cgi.exe`. That's the executable you'll have to run.

With CGI, script information and request headers are sent via environment variables, ie:

```
CGI.StartInfo.info.EnvironmentVariables["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] = @"c:/wwwroot/index.php";
```

For a more elaborate example see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

HTTP headers such as cookies are also sent via environment variables. They are prefixed with `'HTTP_'` and dashes are converted to underscores:

```
CGI.StartInfo.info.EnvironmentVariables["HTTP_COOKIE"] = ...
```

If your request body contains data, you have to set the `CONTENT_LENGTH` environment variable and write the data to the `CGI.StandardInput` after starting the process.